# Largest Compatible Maze

Tags: code-challenge, optimization, maze

## Background

Consider an \$n\times n\$ grid, where each cell is either empty (denoted by `.`) or a wall (denoted by `#`). We say that two cells are *adjacent* if they share an edge (a corner is not enough). A *path* is a sequence of distinct empty cells \$s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_k\$ such that cells \$s_i\$ and \$s_{i+1}\$ are adjacent for \$0\le i<k\$.

We say that a grid is a *maze* if the following conditions hold.

1. There is at most one path between any two empty cells.
2. The following two \$2\times 2\$ patterns do not occur anywhere in the grid.

```
  #.             .#
  .#             #.
```

A maze is **not** required to be connected (i.e. it is allowed to have two empty cells without any paths between them).

Here are a few examples of mazes.

```
.###                 #...                 ....
.###                 ###.                 #.##
.#..                 ..#.                 #.##
.###                 #...                 ....
```

Here are a few examples of grids which are **not** mazes.

```
....                 ##.#      Do not satisfy rule 1.
#.#.                 #..#
#...                 #..#
##.#                 #.##
```

```
##..                 ##.#      Do not satisfy rule 2.
..#.                 ##.#
#.#.                 .#.#
#...                 #..#
```

## Challenge

[Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Delfad0r/505bb7d5bff2a9fecc55ba349be861b4/raw/4a2be7566079c662ed68f8d6ac521099b2b72f67/maze.txt) is a \$128\times 128\$ maze. It has \$991\$ empty cells and \$15393\$ walls. Your task is to tear down as many walls as possible, making sure that the grid you obtain is still a maze.

More formally, let \$M\$ be the maze given above. A submission to this challenge consists of a \$128\times 128\$ maze \$M'\$ such that every empty cell in \$M\$ is also empty in \$M'\$.

### Scoring

This is [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge): the more walls you manage to tear down, the better.

Your score will be equal to the number of walls (`#`) in the maze you submit. Lower score is better.

### Notes

- The maze \$M\$ given above doesn't have any special properties, to the best of my knowledge. It was generated as randomly as possible, fixing the average density of empty cells.
- [Here](https://tio.run/##tVxbb6NGFH7O/IrZ@AGsZT8l7Uu1qvu2@1qp2j5UllVRm8Tj2oAAb@KN8tvTATu2gbmcGShSYhtmzpw5l@9cwM4P1TpLf34rxY9kdv/TLywrxKNI4@3fu1ieCYJg4njAe0TrPN4/seuLUMwH1O87I2FYHooz53PMSANKlgj7B1k2zFPOSpHQJ16G2hiAl76heVV8ZHbbwSimqZmENgO4ZlklXoNJ6pkyjesyoGFzJAdVTWE@pjbAVtAyjCMDUJHwUqq7F@m9ACOsQ8IkRiAH41IAkSV0bPjMgEL2miXhaACALxD52AFsqKSGJaZbEoptQDuIGBAUImRt3jCOfYMuKzYZ8YCLIZzOMx/XMdClCb9rA2a4BYlcfxSgI92KhhgAIupgASebYV3e0fIbKNM0j6ihHcI89my4CiOUQheOYche7IvhfQHYMbOvtW5WDHdRg65yqKMhSHmd1vrIqoDKStiwJJcataEdzqzEVTAA0xk0n0DjEgx@Dob6cAQ9PRKqARQEFIav10KnAgxIi3UhvQMD6EgAZFilpV2OMZP1bUYvW1AqUEclsE6m3icOUhVICdqgpOUYIE33y10GoM8vMFTiWjdErxNBX2hYCgmfnLBjMPDGH2tG5LgxexcH1gaFprSgS5mEWKpo2Gs8OERzP/WDFg19gBdOeY2RAfjjsVPaxHTbcC5GnLNbHzcE0bkdMIMBTqEdlh1ZWgXwalIRWyUugtepAJrNAqZ0EAP46TPwP/UEodYgLnUBFL4Ao3oxGX5AWZjAbgE2dwCMlc7VZeYA485hCWYkg2c0VGdrvumr1Q0BL6Vf2RWMxQvzjnZkhmCseRmxFDZ5FTVdACEWYEQXM3pJuzAZjVrLakhIfHFDjLvFttgN9BkhuINQtXmDtRsOYORx5IQEo/vmaEmpZ7rYZgBj@b7tTiHM94zcpA5LdwjuKgBouRhAVzR0GSW8bADjG8zFDdHBMv/7mJrOs6oRJE8yI32nezBXtqHPSnp9CKaxLmeEU0R@@BghTKFzkLNCTZINMDF0CwMfI2VjtAIoYbd76v2Pea8C8iM7xuy526r1atOQWmywl2a49gBMRgzUhpydkWfBE4oshLtIqBQURugHKjhEhwFY7R/muAt4OArz9S6iSGAL1WygYDH09gUz@61DFjSgQ@JkYvC1OQ12MZt8QYk4A7hibs@KWYTl4a5soDMPxgYyEnoXRZboMDAcQx99LZ5rbdFYdgK4II@rCggPtvSfBYBfQsO68EPcATn7hCpTVkoADnmPc4kEU5fsui8LkG8HQIMRINkgoTiFqyKc9w9fIPJLmZW3t3BOSIY/OGv0Cj11ZkR82LJDuMLHBI6xAOOW5EYGjA8l@X@vwVKneOWE0BbFADGRGhCOMcxtVHfNMFzC8GaO6YwE1sA7Qq6CzmO9gOVpHlwPwyj9Res3LPywGBoUUzUqYZMxFBWdOV21IwsUt2wwDGB8RzH9luGe7nm4AiNMhxZVcXwSDar@CGgk2UhY41gkQhcLRuo9OAxmw8oQh6gxPBZgaB0AOwO4gJ0yjMBT7hi9OIWn6vvzGIFbYGznJ0oAo94iQS@7gjIcO/W7HHq4uiyVUp5j4tHIpoqEkZssnZ7k4FS1/y0bQhOy2yPo3g/ySsnQyQbGvjcHVy@AHlZBLxdAEiJ0KgBBET6P12i/4GDv7UP99YveNxmcbzIwv3z6nCD6PO4Jt4zo@kamf6kKWpOK7ISGvhH8GLAUBo4GakTw9pAgCFDmW1GF07dV8sCX62T5b/PjBOFu@plxeTxkBRdcpLyI08ckrH/K4NP96dr79Y3hen08z@Q6m0yk4Xw3F4v5ZhHJ14/37@/kq/xwPif/LaYtAuKBP8s15kFt6EEU1NYQLNqL1EeRVPsi5cFKxI9ZGm@3Bx6vNvEySSue7PLqwJfJdlsGzcTvohRVsprN51/jbZmodjJdKLY/XTTTa3mtHspQRJsoF1G@udq05DdOD@Fc/HoXbeSf@G1Wz4w2x9dFRz4ntr8V@@SaxElWs1kwCUgTTjs6TlPOaHZ6vtAaP2tRq/f9HB3qnf8QeTi/i@6ju@iT1NL8@Ca66@5CMhAeBfFhFoqPz9Hm42Eq5bDiaVYdRXU8GUmRTbXKa7PY3alKH0Zj7DN5ESuCM3stUbSZlvqV2@0Z9bW97fbbSuTbhOdxtT6Z1zXnbDebL5ia95uqOMj/NzvEeZ6kq1Ck@V465JTdJM/LJK/4l9@/fimKrKhH5XFZshu5i22SSh@dzUR9toiFNOAvzXCRpeFD8G2d8MdCrPg6LvmLeOVF9lTKtcsqiVc8e@Av9fKvwfRCTO5daq4@rSb5R/bUUKopygmP1Zq/nCe@amnXjvDcSFOk0nGDo2nVYmgmqtf6M02e82QpNSIxKS5i@a5oJHfkoSat1vWNXDIMW7@zckGc@lWKLAwaDAmmzXiN8Gqg4Nl5xYgvs@1@l/KXzSvf7cuK/5McIUXyctTgSW/Mpo1dViS8WsfpSU6NaiSVvrYbZRdJOWvhMpNClSc/NA772bicKBvBx7ye2gi@Wtev2232JNJHSSYus/Qzv32RBF9vJRN5IdIqbCg0cySF7/FWrOSlcikZPyP5bopltq/HTs7THoK/sn3Bm4H1zJfm3SsPD9meV/XJVfYkt317e6TRUtM7vdvJ7ZR/4qepTxLEy2kwfXv7Dw) is a python script that checks whether your submission is valid and tells you your score (just paste the maze in the "Input" section)

Comment: Suggest an invalid case because of 2*2 `.`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this challenge is going to have many ties, since the optimum solution is any tree. Maybe it would be more interesting as `code-golf`.

Comment: @xigoi If you are correct, I'm going to be very sad :(. I won't change the scoring criterion now, but maybe in the future I'll post a new challenge.

Comment: @xigoi However, I believe things may be a bit more complicated than you think. For instance, consider [these](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Delfad0r/dcea98e6dc83559db9b8d71574999c78/raw/c29efd073d362dcae73dff4d56421c87352434f5/gistfile1.txt) mazes. They are both maximal trees, but they have a different number of empty cells.

Comment: I think the score would be a little easier to understand and test if it were just the number of walls in the final maze, with lower being better.

Comment: @xnor That was the scoring system I first thought of, but then I (perhaps mistakenly) decided that scoring answers by the number of walls removed would be more natural. However, since there is only one answer at the moment and you are way more experienced than me, I'm going to edit the question (and hyper-neutrino's answer) to use the scoring system you have proposed.

Answer (score 10):

## Score: <s>8066</s> 8065 walls

I found an 8066 wall solution using dynamic programming over solutions that can be recursively decomposed by splitting on a row or column consisting entirely of floors or entirely of walls.  The implementation of this apparently simple idea was rather more complicated than its description, since there are 17 different types of subproblems depending on the borders and the connectivity between them.

I then removed one wall by hand-editing seven cells in rows 119–122, columns 60–63.

This is an **optimal** solution.  Proof:

Add a one-cell border using \$516\$ extra walls. Consider the planar graph whose vertices are the \$w\$ centers of walls, and whose edges are the \$a\$ wall-wall adjacencies. This graph is connected (because any component of walls not connected to the border would be encircled by a forbidden cycle of floors), and has \$f \ge 2\$ faces (at least an inside and outside). By Euler’s formula, \$w - a + f = 2\$, so \$w - a \le 0\$.

Now consider the different planar graph whose vertices are the \$131^2\$ corner points of walls, and whose edges are the \$4w - a\$ sides of walls. None of these \$131^2\$ vertices are missing (because an isolated one would again be encircled by a forbidden cycle of floors). This graph is again connected and has \$f' \ge w + 2\$ faces. By Euler’s formula, \$131^2 - (4w - a) + f' = 2\$, so \$131^2 - 3w + a \le 0\$.

Adding these two inequalities gives \$131^2 - 2w \le 0\$, so \$w \ge \frac{131^2}{2} = 8064.5 + 516\$.

[Validate](https://tio.run/##zV1Lcxu5ET4bv2LWOJCs5X5lJ5fUVpTb7jVVqc0hpVKlGImyRqFIFkmtpbj8250ZPmbQQDfQwIzXpiyRnAcG@NDvbsDb18PDZv3nL/v6f8ur93/6i9ns6g/1erH699OiOTKZTGzmC8VXkOO4fDPuSTD3A/xn70pEHg/mSHfMRNsA2yXF@KHGxhTizEKiv7G/NNUBFM03hHfmq0nTDkYhTeEm0A7A7TIHb4Qk5U7FrvM7IHRzJAblbjElpDaAVkAI49QBcE0UTWo@F8lcgBGeo5JJRtEcoo8ClF2CR8NdBxjshUcikwCAUkFUQgdISSVeLBnpkWCGAfEipUJgIDS0bxiHvqHHytgRX8ghhPNxU8I6kXZ14Ps0EBe3UDUXXgVITRNtiAFChFcWyKIZ4/cdhG/AmmkFWkO8xBSMOXIWUVEKSR0jYr2kH4bLA5CWmeGs@VYx8qGGfsrBa0Oo7DqR@tRTAY5KzDAjV6u1IV5uko1zYgCxIzh@g66XMChjMLSvTKEnS0JegEIhhVHKtZCmAAPMYkmle2IAHgJQi1Wd2ZWpM01IMzK20HigmZNgPEs9bBwqL1CjtKExyzEAzfzTfgcg2xcYirjIhggiEfoHDTMhUWITegSDYvmTtIgyB5aO4iAZoBBcCz3KKonFacMg8JChzcumHzptWCJ4kWXXRDuAcnmcZTYZaRjZzki2dVvChlAyd4bMMECWakdiRIlQAYqCVMpQSQ7w0hRAGCwQMwcxoD9hB75STBD8DKL3C8DwAqLTCzv8BdYxQZoCUuwARD0d57TJEOPZaglxSYZCbchba6Xma5INgaJJd@gKUefFFGs7dYcQ9XmN0hWOcZXWXIBCF2BEFotyCXVMRmuNUI1KEvdsiHGHSGGPtG8Uyh0Kr61YWOfJAYx8ndogwei8OZpRWmgu0g5gLN5PZQoRzxnloY5EdAj5UwDobDFAP9GQLEoU0QDGJ5ieDeHJsvI8phB55gJBzUETbT8rB@PQhmyVBHEII1BXtoRjND9KiBAx1TmIWcE3aQaQGHzHoIRIzRihAI3a9Q9dfk3xU6Au2Ylaz36otihMowqxIe2aweUA2BEVdcRmN@q7UCiKEg37kpAFCiPEA5kewusAkvSPuN4FChjFlHKXEhKkVLUZCCyGpi9MnG8zrKABEZIsEkMpzQmyy6TwhUbjDOiVyasVS4BVwK5mIDMPlg1qSVjsFCW0w0B1DFn7Jjg3GaJJjATIkTy5U6AobAlrAVBm0Bhf/ChHoLY@wVnKLALIsHuyXSTEomRuXBZQpwMgyAioaFDhnCJ3IrLHj1JBVGYys@ktdAbJ8MLZKFfIrZuoxEfKOkSu@LDI1AUY1yWPdiBalFS@riHhpxTZhBCdYkBpSA1QxxjGNlzWDMMRRnHnjEQkSCreEWwVeGW9QKKaB@5lGCW@mFxhUSaLIUgxLlCJFMZgPLq4uZqWLGBSNhgmYEqvMvKQkW/uFbCCUdwOUariVIkGLj4CXZNmJFmT6SRC0gUjxR4yLjbD3JAMrTFcF2CoH4B0B9ALO1aNoBB3jO6conDqw/uMorfA2MyvRACjpkgQWFdg1XFWvCsjhitZqRr3HLYgkK2FxKiDLF5McrCpGq6yUQQh/RiBnw8qMsngWQNj5@aQywWQxSr07gJUIEKaAigmoqS8RlzgkI7tg19@EaxkyE4ymDJ7ujMQS8o9kWcRuYnMclcVuiCVmgkjcSOUdSDhGGQSaFSC00smkwn221V9mM6@3C3vq9uH5e1/j5sTTJ9mP5uqed1vdlVd1etqt1h/WE7brQx@en8@dzn/GDnfvl6umuc8bur19Prpur65fryZN@8/vr98at6bL92x5s/NjDRQ31cvzTOuJy2hT@aTlhomN/Qh7Wu3PDzv1tXkrl582KwXq9Vrtbh7XNwu14dq@bQ9vFa3y9VqPzne@Hu9rw/Lu6vr618Xq/2SG8nshhn@7OZ4e4vX3f1@Ws8f59t6vn10Bt30d7F@nV7Xf303f2x@679dtXfOH0/vNx4@527/tnteuk2csbq6mtiJ6obziE63sXccR9qdINdfkdbacb/MX9uR/6/eTq/fzd/P381/ambp@vRh/s4fRdOB6QmIH66m9Y8v88cfX2cNDnfVenM4QXU6OG8gm4mTR7voj5Sbjygxhp3sYcWk6x6Bgna6md9muAFRu/T29Lw61NvVstouDg9n8nJ7bp6urm8M3/c3h91r8/fNExbb7XJ9N63X2@eGIWfmzfLldrk9VL/8/ddfdrvNrr1qu9jvzZtmFKvluuHRq6u6Pbpb1A0B/3K8vN6sp/eT3x6W1YddfVc9LPbVp/pztdt83DfP3h@Wi7tqc199ah//eTLrG2vG3sxce5hv8h@bj8eW2habGz4cHqpP3Y2fxbZbRng5olmvG8adnEirheF4I/@sf66XL9vlbTMjjUxa7BbNp90RuVMf2qb5uX7TPHI6Jfus9BKnfW8gm06OMmQyO14vgNcKimrTPXFe3W5Wz0/r6tPj5@rpeX@o/rM8iZSmL6cZPM@bSc3G02a3rA4Pi/UZp@PUNK2Es32c7N1yf0XksmlAbQ7@cGTYn6OPq/dH4BdVe@sR@MND@75abT7W6w9NM4v9Zv1z9fZT0@Dnt00ntrt6fZgeWzje07Tw@2JV3zWn9rdNxztJ/jTD7ea5vdZ2t91P/rV53lXHC9s7Px0/fa6mr5vn6tAevNt8bIb99u2pDTJNl/be2rez6qfqfOvHRojvZ5PZly99GOT8e/RfyVH6M/LLXBrulhbj8hmX71534h6Gequc84@JIoC@a06H3NCRc8I/FF7nfOjNFRcBd@mm0y7IBFh3xTroHPU9IX1zz3tHGATg0wBpgSLgdGMUGmARgE@I7oCgdiEFUzAXAUqSfToD0vzbyAlLpiBCA949wZQKc4/wOuaUwTd@GcvsLWD/yK1yOsqGM8OeOKSsfP7nigv6h4oRxCWpcUWNdT9ZbhKdPH13myM6KZ97QqxjGYKSIbTOIoCRELA9WysQcAReQPceAvQ2@uYhwMQ8DJUBtgAB6BHARXowCLiqUIOAIzagRKC/GGMgMJJtYLw9RvQIILLVVs5WOb4e0CNgyWn0E93BozGhyhEIdQgkHomGsL69LkBuNi@2gU/JVjnnnljB/KVzSM@HctBGbYLgMehWJXcxQWLKsSOBIP8jip9GPamKMcTMsbkIjCEH3FCt320uXQvtnPsehxRJdscmIBBSh2zy88aEDFYcgcDs9oxl0T7MSmekEAjXJ/T2MAMFOA6QlQdBgCVdjgitYCsxlA4qXS27U43AupzbMb4kdMfGcoGrlZCROA@lSWKrHFhJkoToWo5imCkEIi7JxTl1tTB4IpQsbMFlJLRnc5QRQYAcTMhaATcNR34PrpmywMMfVSghypL7rsbx7G53MoN5pfKzp5LQHved@hCB0CMPpQ2XZQMnfEiltUtNcAQLi4BNIeBLDGq0BuqEAzCBgFUgAOu7Y@gkthdF8qNUo9BAGNPrwbOO/xf4afEABTQIUIXkax0aU4SnpyCvYTbEbYwhQLL85AKbQsD2QRBBGRG/VELAsx67MSLwRxkEwG6WAWfDKNYv9ZxtOlAPASCOQCxEE9KAbz57fEaYHyDumWirIMEFURronE6JBgbpAjeqBJ8XiEsaeqQYVhSD78U5/aZb5fixGTHIDO5w8MHaIGQluayeRcQb1JxVF01GpF1VSjZpBCw1Mr9SgAKsUezpV2jL2YUKE36rHDUCZHqtTVnJwfwTcU4RgA6BKAX4xCqnroJgNQ2tRRAA64lLHoI2epFEgPMxFcmYjK1yvgO/IKtsE5LrWegeGD6mIPt9JGQhiLcMB@64mzErK5E4wpFg767kRctl15J3NiVZ6yWN1FNgvy0RIqOG8WttleNYzEF8jGZ/vkIZhYGz5MBaLzThJ42tr5S4Ot5IyJgIKfQI@FyACDMhEM7UqrU2zYaunO7kQBCutNIUIEymWy8hJj5WlgPUHRBYkDAiI3qEEIBOEmqJkCmqQVAGHwl8MkRoEfr@ge/LIRDG5DVGoEe530kBg5CuH61kwasHcFM4hkRGnLVIATHwRlOYueLyFpaxo6xTR2RJRRDjwkDIRYNk8RgTSvYaAm2IfucIONKlDwoMQcCzJN0kgKGRYAAIloTI2XgQllAj4Gpgnwb6eAe8vBU7TFuCAPli2Fg4oVsmaB4pb4khoLeKaUDI/lFygKN@gNspAim/Ty85ogg4REiTmEzYsrTqU4WAu2F6YKRC9qHLPSMRAcEwDyKVup8IAgRnUsJJ1AQABgGFPdRnXwUEfL1sz/ILNvCQ8hEgFleoDS0x9JwMRWiOYYQaAgPwQQF/n6uuiBWcuIovJ0xslcOpfxYBy3kGXmqXDdVYr9SEzR37NBAgEJRc28CWlSMzhJ9IExIXFCDAewReHU3gHpQjwLpCclCTUVbHLhgI//triACKaSCKgOWEt7cUmOECaq1IxRMsAqEo1tDACFXksjKK0oCL@Bib@AVb5UQR8DxQpo7BD08mi8o9PXNJXLLsS4mQqR8Tg5maonI3WJ1Wx/ar0gCz@MP66piShmbVrVI7Gs8vJzRgKQ14LrouIBnQCauMHAffHSqJxvjy38nUI4gagFYjRcyVDgGvbttfvcIgQIMGvgPFhm4ZKjKWM2VZGvArrOi6IAGBZHjX8MELhCYZFzfyyxVLyvm@eYQE6aXXw2IkiXyKASnFZnSQunRLa5ZTgjNOEYy/5YAq0IhoR6Aq7e4WHUTplZdpkRJAnZdAEehcwZNk@GOI0EWgN10T/w3ZwK1yEggE9Iv08jGlXgi3unAQYMqTxPxR8kBk0ZlIA99KEJF4po2Xt2pSnBkln7AOAlR3eakLG7g@4NYV5f2c/hjXZwwRgN8tr7zNMhn9/BCN41noEbCFCITeMedUsghcfCMEyaHMYl9vvSFIrQStzKQBmK9jFTsIWBGBYHUTu2ikbKscikCKBvxcGdhCzyEIsFoMHjewrgTKdnYzftELk6K0TCkPa7LovQV/6XfClgETkIzVS@S8/g8)

```
.#.#.#.#...#...#.#..#..#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#................................................................................
.#.#.#.##.##.###...##.##.#.#.###.....#.#.#.#...#.##########.###########.########.##################.#################.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#...#...#.#..#..#.#.#...#.##.##.#.#.#.###...#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..##########
.#.#.#.##.###.##.####.##.#.#.###.#...#.#.#.#.#...###.#.#.####.....#.#.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.##.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#...#...#....#..#.#.#.#...#####.#.#.#.###...#.#.#.#..##.####.............................................................
.#.#.#.##.###.##.####.##.#.#.###.....#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.##.....####.####################################################.###.
.#.#.#.#...#...#....#..#.#.#.#...#####.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#..###.###.#...#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.
.#.#.#.##.###.##.####.##.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##
................................................................................................................................
##.##.###.#############.#############################################################.#######################################.##
.###...#...#.....#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#....#..#.#.#..#.#..#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#................
.#.##.##.#.####.##.#.######.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.####.##.##.#...##.##.#.##.#.#.####.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.....##########.######
.#.#...#####.....#.#..#..#..#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#....#..#.#.#..#.#..#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.###.###................
.#.##.##.#.####.##.#.##.###.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.##.####.##.##.#.####.##.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#...#.####.############
.#.#...#...#..#..#.#..#..#..#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#....#..#.#....#.#..#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.###...#..###...........
.#.##.###.###...##.#.##.###.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.##.###.###.##.###.##.##.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.###.##.#.##########
.#.#...#...#..#..#.#..#..#..#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#..#.#....................................................................
.#.##.###.#####.##.#.##.###.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.##.###...######.#############.#####.#################.########################
.#.#...#...#.....#.#..#..#..#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#..###.#.#...#..#...#.#.###..#..#.#...#.#.#...............................
.#.##.###.#####.##.#.##.###.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.###.##.##.#.#.##.####.##.##.#.################################
................................................................................................................................
#.#######.##################.######################.#.####.###################.#####################.##.####.##################.
#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.......#.............#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#..#.#..#.#..###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#..##
..####.####...#.#.#.#.#.####################.##.#.#.#...##.##.#.##.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.######.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.
#.#.....#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.......#.............#.#.#.#.#.#...#...................................................................
..#######.#...#.#.#.#.#.#####.#####.###########.#.############.#####################.##.##.#.#.#.##.##.######.##################
#.......#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.......#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#.#..#..#........................
..#######.#...#.#.#.#.#.######.####...........#.#.#.###.....####.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#############################################
#.......#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.......#.#.###########.#.#...###.###..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#...................
..#######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.######.##.............#.#.#.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.##.######.#############
#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.......####.##########.................................................................................
........#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#####.###.#..#.#.#....#######.#####.#############################.#.#.#############.#############.######
#.##.####.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.###.##.#.#.###.#.###.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.
..#.....#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.......#.#..#...#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#...............................
#.#######.##.##.#.#.#.#.######.##.##.##.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.##################################
................................................................................................................................
########.#############.##################.#.##.##.#######.#.#.###########.######################################################
.....#......#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#..#.#...#######.#...#..#...#.#...#.#...#.#..#.#.#..#.....#.#.#.#................
###.####.##.#.#.###.##.#.###.#.#.#.##.#############.#.###.#.#.#.#.###.##.#.#.#.###.###.#.##.#.#.#.######.........###############
.....#...#..#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#...#.........#.#...#...#.#.#...#..#####.#...#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#...#.#.#.#.#................
###.####.####.#.###.##.#.###.#.#.#.##.#########.###.#.####.##.#.#.###.##...#.#.###...#.#.##.#.#.#.####.#.#######################
.....#......#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#...#.#.#...#..#.###.#...#.###.#.#..#.#.#..#.#..........................
##.#.###.####.#.###.##.#.###.#.#.#.##.###.........#.#.####.##.#.#.#.#.##...#.##.##.#...#.##.#.#.#.##...#.#################.#####
.#.###...#..#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#...#####.#####.#...#...#.#.#.###..#.###.#...#.###.#.#..#.#.#..#####...#....................
.....###...##.#.###.##.#.###.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.....#.#.####.##.#.#...#.##.#.#.##.##.#...#.##.#.#.#.##.....###.#.##############.##
##.###...#..#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.....#.###.#...#...#.#.#.###..#...#.#...#.###.#.#..#.#.#..#####.#.#.#.#................
.#.#.###.####.#.###.####.#.#.#.#.#.##...#####.#...#.##.###.##.#.#...#.###.##.##.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#####################
.....#...#..#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#.###..#..#####.#...#...#.#.#.###...........................................................
###.####.#.##.#.###.#.###.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.##.#.#.#.##.###.##.#.#.#.##########################################################.#
................................................................................................................................
#.###.###.################################.####################.################.###########.#######.###################.##.####
....#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.###.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#......
#.#########.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#########
....#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.#####...................................................................................
#.####.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#...#.#.#.#...##########.######.##################################.########.#.##############.#####
....#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.#.###.#.#..#.###.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.###.#.#.#..###.#.#...............
#.#.##.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#########.######
..###..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.#...#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#..#......................................
#.#.##.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#######################################
................................................................................................................................
###.#################################.##########.######.#.#.####################.###############################################
.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#...#.#.#######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#######...........................................
.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#####.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.####.#######################################
.##.............................................................................................................................
.#..########################################.###################################################################################
.##...#.......#.#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#.#.#...........................................................................
.#..#.#####.###.#.######.##.#.#.#.#.#.###.#####.#...###############.############.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.##.#####.#####
.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...###.#.#.#...#.#.....#...#..#.###..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.........
.#....#.......#.#.###.#.###.#.#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#...#.#.#.#.###.###.###.###.##.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.##.######.####.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.##.##.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.........############################################
.#....#.......#.#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#...#.....#.#.#.#...#.###.###...#######.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.......................
.##.#######.###.#.######.##.#.#.#.#.##.##.##.##.#####.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.################.#######
................................................................................................................................
##.########.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.############################################.#############################.######.#.#.#.######.###.##
....#.#..#..#######..#.#.#.#.......#.#.#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.###..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.
.#.##.##.####.....###############.##...#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.####.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.........
.#..#.#..#..####.##..#.....#.......#.###..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#....####.#####
##.##.##.#.##.....#.#####.#######.##.#.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.........
....#.#..#..###.###..#.....#.......#...#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.
##.##.##.#.##.#.#.#.###.######.#.####.##.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.#####################
.....................#.....#.###.#.#............................................................................................
##.######################.##.......#####.############.######.########.#.#################################################.######
.....................#.....######.##.#......#...#.#.###.........#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.............................................
##.######################.##.......#.###.####.###.#.#.#.##.##.###.#.#...#.#.#.#...##############################################
.....................#.....######.##.#......#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.##.##.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....
##.###################.#.###.......#.#.#.####...#.#.#.#######...#.#.#...#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#...###.##
.....................###.#.######.##.###....##.##.#.#.#...#.#.###.#.##.##.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.###.#.#.
##.########.#.#.##.#.#.....#.......#.#...##.#...#.#.#.#.###.....#...............................................................
....#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.####.#######.##.###.#..##.##.#.#.#.#.###.######.#######.###################.###.#.##.######################
##.##.#.#.############.....#.......#.#...####...#.#.#.#.........#.#..#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.###.#..#.#..#.#..............
.....................####.#######.##.###....##.##.#.#.###.#######.####.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.######.##.#...#.#.#.###.###
##.###################.....#.......#.#...####...#.#.#.#.........#.#..#.#.###..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#...#..
.....................####.#######.##.###....##.##.#.#.###########.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.###...#
.#.####.##############.....#.......#.#...#.##...#.#.#.#.........#.#..#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#...#..
##.#.................####.###.######.###.#..##.##.#.#.########.##.#.##.#.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.###############
...###################.....#.......#.#.#.####...................................................................................
##...................####.######.#.#.#......##.##########################.######################################.#####.#########
...###################.....#.#.#.###.###.####...#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.###.#...#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.###........
##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.##.......#.#......##.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#####
.....................#.....######.##.###.####...................................................................................
##.###########.#.#.#.###.###.......#.#......####.####.###############################.###.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.......#.#.#...#######.....###.#.###.###.##.#.#...#.....#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.###.################
##.#####...#####.....####.##.###.#.#.#....###.#######.###.###...#.#.......#.#.#.#...#...#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.......##.##.#.##.####.....#.#.#.#.#.###.##.#.#...#.....#.#.##.##.##.###.##.#.#.##.##.###.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.###.................
##.#.#.#.............###.###.......#.#....#.#.#.#####.###...#...#.#..#....#.#.#.#...#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.################.##.#.#.######.##.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.###.##.##.######.#.#.##.#############################################
................................................................................................................................
.###.####.##########.####################################################.#######################.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#########
...#..#.#...#.....#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...........
.###.##...#####.###.##.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#...#.#...################################
...#..###...#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.###.##...###.....#.##...##.....................................................................................................
...#..###...####.##.#..#..##########.#################.################.######################################.######.#.#.#.#.#.
.###.##...###.....#########.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..###.#..############
...#..###.#.####.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.###.##.........................................................................................................................
...#..#.#.###.#####.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#################################.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.
.###.##.#.#.#.....#.#...#.#.###.#.#####.#.###..#.#.#.#....#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#..
.#.#..#.#...#.#####.##.##.#.#...#.#.....#.#...##.#.#.##.###...##.#.##.#.#.#.#.##################################################
...#.##.#.###.....#.#...#.#.###.#.#####.#.###..#.#.#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..............
.###..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#...#.#.....#..#..##.#.#.##.#.####.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.############.##
...#.##.#...#.#####.#...#.#.###.#.##.##.#.###...................................................................................
.###..#.#.###.#.#.#.##.##.#.#...#.#..#..#..#..###.#.#.####.###.##.#.#.#.#.##.##.##############.#################################
...#.##.#...#.....#.#...#.#.###.#.#####.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.....#...#.#.#.#.#.#...#...#.............................................
.###..#.#.###.##.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.....#.#.#.###########.#.#.#.#.##.##.#######################.########################
...#.##.#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#...#.#.#####.#.#.#.###.#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#..#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.............................................
```

## Score: 8066

This is the unedited solution from the dynamic programming algorithm.

[Validate](https://tio.run/##zV1Lbxs5Ej6Hv6InPEjCKB@S3csiWO8tc11gMXtYGMZAa8txe2VJkOSJPUF@e7ZbkrtZZBVZZHcmkWNL6geb/FjvKjLb58PdZv3Xr/v6j@XFu7/8zWx29cd6vVj99rBojkwmE5v5QvEV5Dhevhn3JJj7Af6zdyUijwdzpDtmom2A7ZJi/FBjYwpxZiHR39hfmuoAiuYbwjvz1aRpB6OQpnATaAfgdpmDN0KScqdi1/kdELo5EoNyt5gSUhtAKyCEceoAuCaKJjWfi2QuwAjPUckko2gO0UcByi7Bo@GuAwz2wiORSQBAqSAqoQOkpBIvloz0SDDDgHiRUiEwEBraN4xD39BjZeyIL@QQwvm4KWGdSLs68H0aiItbqJoLrwKkpok2xAAhwisLZNGM8fsOwjdgzbQCrSFeYgrGHDmLqCiFpI4RsV7SD8PLA5CWmeGs@VYx8qGGfsrBa0Oo7DqR@tRTAY5KzDAjV6u1IV5uko1zYgCxIzh@g66XMChjMLSvTKEnS0JegEIhhVHKtZCmAAPMYkmle2IAHgJQi1Wd2ZWpM01IMzK20HigmZNgPEs9bBwqL1CjtKExyzEAzfzTfgcg2xcYirjIhggiEfoHDTMhUWITegSDYvmTtIgyB5aO4iAZoBBcCz3KKonFacMg8JChzcumHzptWCJ4kWXXRDuAcnmcZTYZaRjZzki2dVvChlAyd4bMMECWakdiRIlQAYqCVMpQSQ7w0hRAGCwQMwcxoD9hB75RTBD8DKL3C8DwAqLTCzv8BdYxQZoCUuwARD0d57TJEOPZaglxSYZCbchba6Xma5INgaJJd@gKUefFFGs7dYcQ9XmN0hWOcZXWXIBCF2BEFotyCXVMRmuNUI1KEvdsiHGHSGGPtG8Uyh0Kr61YWOfJAYx8ndogwei8OZpRWmgu0g5gLN5PZQoRzxnloY5EdAj5UwDobDFAP9GQLEoU0QDGJ5ieDeHJsvI8phB55gJBzUETbT8rB@PQhmyVBHEII1BXtoRjND9KiBAx1TmIWcE3aQaQGHzHoIRIzRihAI3a9Q@9/Jrip0BdshO1nv1QbVGYRhViQ9o1g8sBsCMq6ojNbtR3oVAUJRr2JSELFEaIBzI9hNcBJOkfcb0LFDCKKeUuJSRIqWozEFgMTV@YON9mWEEDIiRZJIZSmhNkl0nhC43GGdArk1crlgCrgF3NQGYeLBvUkrDYKUpoh4HqGLL2TXBuMkSTGAmQI3lyp0BR2BLWAqDMoDG@@FGOQG19grOUWQSQYfdku0iIRcncuCygTgdAkBFQ0aDCOUXuRGSPH6WCqMxkZtNb6AyS4YWzUa6QWzdRiY@UdYhc8WGRqQswrkse7UC0KKl8XUPCTymyCSE6xYDSkBqgjjGMbbisGYYjjOLOGYlIkFS8I9gq8Mp6gUQ1D9zLMEp8MbnCokwWQ5BiXKASKYzBeHRxczUtWcCkbDBMwJReZeQhI9/cK2AFo7gdolTFqRINXHwEuibNSLIm00mEpAtGij1kXGyGuSEZWmO4LsBQPwDpDqAXdqwaQSHuGN05ReHUh/cZRW@BsZlfiQBGTZEgsK7AquOseFdGDFeyUjXuOWxBIFsLiVEHWbyY5GBTNVxlowhC@jECPx9UZJLBswbGzs0hlwsgi1Xo3QWoQIQ0BVBMREl5jbjAIR3bB7/8IljJkJ1kMGX2dGcglpR7Is8ichOZ5a4qdEEqNRNG4kYo60DCMcgk0KgEp5dMJhPst6v6MJ19vVneVtd3y@v/HTcnmD7M3puqed1udlVd1etqt1h/XE7brQzevDufezl/Hznfvp4umufcb@r19PLhsr66vL@aN@8/v3v51Lw3X7pjzZ@rGWmgvq2emmdcTlpCn8wnLTVMruhD2tdueXjcravJTb34uFkvVqvnanFzv7herg/V8mF7eK6ul6vVfnK88fd6Xx@WNxeXl78sVvslN5LZFTP82dXx9havm9v9tJ7fz7f1fHvvDLrp72L9PL2s//52ft/81v@4aO@c35/erzx8zt3@dfe4dJs4Y3VxMbET1Q3nEZ1uY@84jrQ7Qa6/IK21436aP7cj/6PeTi/fzt/N387fNLN0efowf@uPounA9ATETxfT@uen@f3Pz7MGh5tqvTmcoDodnDeQzcTJo130R8rNR5QYw072sGLSdY9AQTvdzG8z3ICoXXp7eFwd6u1qWW0Xh7szebk9Nw8Xl1eG7/urw@65@fvqAYvtdrm@mdbr7WPDkDPzavl0vdweqg///OXDbrfZtVdtF/u9edWMYrVcNzx6cVG3R3eLuiHgD8fL6816ejv59W5ZfdzVN9XdYl99rr9Uu82nffPs/WG5uKk2t9Xn9vFfJrO@sWbszcy1h/km/7X5dGypbbG54ePhrvrc3fhFbLtlhKcjmvW6YdzJibRaGI438s/693r5tF1eNzPSyKTFbtF82h2RO/WhbZqf61fNI6dTss9KL3Ha9way6eQoQyaz4/UCeK2gqDbdE@fV9Wb1@LCuPt9/qR4e94fqv8uTSGn6cprB87yZ1Gw8bHbL6nC3WJ9xOk5N00o428fJ3i33F0QumwbU5uBPR4Z9H31cvT8Cv6jaW4/AH@7a99Vq86lef2yaWew36/fV689Ng19eN53Y7ur1YXps4XhP08Lvi1V905zaXzcd7yT5wwzXm8f2Wtvddjv5z@ZxVx0vbO/8fPz0pZo@bx6rQ3vwZvOpGfbr16c2yDS9tPfavp5Vb6rzrZ8aIb6fTWZfv/ZhkPPv0X8lR@nPyC/z0nC3tBgvn/Hy3etO3MNQb5Vz/jFRBNB3zemQGzpyTviHwuucD7254iLgLt102gWZAOuuWAedo74npG/uee8IgwB8GiAtUAScboxCAywC8AnRHRDULqRgCuYiQEmyT2dAmn8bOWHJFERowLsnmFJh7hFex5wy@M4vY5m9BeyfuVVOR9lwZtgTh5SVz/9ccUH/UDGCuCQ1rqix7ifLTaKTp@9uc0Qn5XNPiHUsQ1AyhNZZBDASArZnawUCjsAL6N5DgN5G3zwEmJiHoTLAFiAAPQJ4kR4MAq4q1CDgiA0oEegvxhgIjGQbGG@PET0CiGy1lbNVjq8H9AhYchr9RHfwaEyocgRCHQKJR6IhrO@vC5CbzYtt4FOyVc65J1Ywf@kc0vOhHLRRmyB4DLpVyV1MkJhy7EggyP@I4qdRT6piDDFzbC4CY8gBN1Trd5tL10I7577HIUWS3bEJCITUIZv8vDEhgxVHIDC7PWNZtA@z0hkpBML1Cb09zEABjgNk5UEQYEmXI0Ir2EoMpYNKV8vuVCOwLud2jC8J3bGxXOBqJWQkzkNpktgqB1aSJCG6lqMYZgqBiEvy4py6Whg8EUoWtuAyEtqzOcqIIEAOJmStgJuGI38E10xZ4OGPKpQQZcl9V@N4drc7mcG8UvnZU0loj/tOfYhA6JGH0obLsoETPqTS2qUmOIKFRcCmEPAlBjVaA3XCAZhAwCoQgPXdMXQS24si@VGqUWggjOn14FnH/wv8tHiAAhoEqELytQ6NKcLTU5DXMBviNsYQIFl@coFNIWD7IIigjIhfKiHgWY/dGBH4owwCYDfLgLNhFOuXes42HaiHABBHIBaiCWnAN589PiPMDxD3TLRVkOCCKA10TqdEA4N0gRtVgs8LxCUNPVIMK4rBj@KcftetcvzYjBhkBnc4@GBtELKSXFbPIuINas6qiyYj0q4qJZs0ApYamd8oQAHWKPb0K7Tl7EKFCb9VjhoBMr3WpqzkYP6JOKcIQIdAlAJ8YpVTV0GwmobWIgiA9cQlD0EbvUgiwPmYimRMxlY5P4BfkFW2Ccn1LHQPDB9TkP0@ErIQxFuGA3fczZiVlUgc4Uiwd1fyouWya8k7m5Ks9ZJG6imw35cIkVHD@K22ynEs5iA@RrM/36CMwsBZcmCtF5rwk8bWV0pcHW8kZEyEFHoEfC5AhJkQCGdq1VqbZkNXTndyIAhXWmkKECbTrZcQEx8rywHqDggsSBiRET1CCEAnCbVEyBTVICiDjwQ@GSK0CH3/wPflEAhj8hoj0KPcH6SAQUjXj1ay4NUDuCkcQyIjzlqkgBh4oynMXHF5C8vYUdapI7KkIohxYSDkokGyeIwJJXsNgTZEv3MEHOnSBwWGIOBZkm4SwNBIMAAES0LkbDwIS6gRcDWwTwN9vANe3oodpi1BgHwxbCyc0C0TNI@Ut8QQ0FvFNCBk/yw5wFE/wO0UgZTfp5ccUQQcIqRJTCZsWVr1qULA3TA9MFIh@9DlnpGIgGCYB5FK3U8EAYIzKeEkagIAg4DCHuqzrwICvl62Z/kFG3hI@QgQiyvUhpYYek6GIjTHMEINgQH4oIC/z1VXxApOXMWXEya2yuHUP4uA5TwDL7XLhmqsV2rC5o59GggQCEqubWDLypEZwk@kCYkLChDgPQKvjiZwD8oRYF0hOajJKKtjFwyE//01RADFNBBFwHLC21sKzHABtVak4gkWgVAUa2hghCpyWRlFacBFfIxN/IKtcqIIeB4oU8fghyeTReWennlJXLLsS4mQqR8Tg5maonI3WJ1Wx/ab0gCz@MP66piShmbVrVI7Gs8vJzRgKQ14LrouIBnQCauMHAffHSqJxvjy38nUI4gagFYjRcyVDgGvbttfvcIgQIMGvgPFhm4ZKjKWM2VZGvArrOi6IAGBZHjX8MELhCYZFzfyyxVLyvm@e4QE6aXXw2IkiXyKASnFZnSQunRLa5ZTgjNOEYy/5YAq0IhoR6Aq7e4WHUTplZdpkRJAnZdAEehcwZNk@HOI0EWgN10T/w3ZwK1yEggE9Iv08jGlXgi3unAQYMqTxPxR8kBk0ZlIA99LEJF4po2Xt2pSnBkln7AOAlR3eakLG7g@tGQuV2g5joJxfcYQAfjd8svbmIx@fojG8Sz0CNAQUda4GWUk0j1JS1kI6ykyi3299YYgtRK0MpMGYL6NVewgYEUEgtVN7KKRsq1yKAIpGvBzZWALPYcgwGoxeNzAuhIo29nN@EUvTIrSMqU8rMmi9xb8pd8JWwZMQDJWL5Hz@j8)

```
.#.#.#.#...#...#.#..#..#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#................................................................................
.#.#.#.##.##.###...##.##.#.#.###.....#.#.#.#...#.##########.###########.########.##################.#################.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#...#...#.#..#..#.#.#...#.##.##.#.#.#.###...#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..##########
.#.#.#.##.###.##.####.##.#.#.###.#...#.#.#.#.#...###.#.#.####.....#.#.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.##.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#...#...#....#..#.#.#.#...#####.#.#.#.###...#.#.#.#..##.####.............................................................
.#.#.#.##.###.##.####.##.#.#.###.....#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.##.....####.####################################################.###.
.#.#.#.#...#...#....#..#.#.#.#...#####.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#..###.###.#...#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.
.#.#.#.##.###.##.####.##.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##
................................................................................................................................
##.##.###.#############.#############################################################.#######################################.##
.###...#...#.....#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#....#..#.#.#..#.#..#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#................
.#.##.##.#.####.##.#.######.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.####.##.##.#...##.##.#.##.#.#.####.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.....##########.######
.#.#...#####.....#.#..#..#..#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#....#..#.#.#..#.#..#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.###.###................
.#.##.##.#.####.##.#.##.###.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.##.####.##.##.#.####.##.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#...#.####.############
.#.#...#...#..#..#.#..#..#..#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#....#..#.#....#.#..#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.###...#..###...........
.#.##.###.###...##.#.##.###.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.##.###.###.##.###.##.##.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.###.##.#.##########
.#.#...#...#..#..#.#..#..#..#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#..#.#....................................................................
.#.##.###.#####.##.#.##.###.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.##.###...######.#############.#####.#################.########################
.#.#...#...#.....#.#..#..#..#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#..#..#..#..###.#.#...#..#...#.#.###..#..#.#...#.#.#...............................
.#.##.###.#####.##.#.##.###.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.###.##.##.#.#.##.####.##.##.#.################################
................................................................................................................................
#.#######.##################.######################.#.####.###################.#####################.##.####.##################.
#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.......#.............#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#..#.#..#.#..###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#..##
..####.####...#.#.#.#.#.####################.##.#.#.#...##.##.#.##.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.######.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.
#.#.....#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.......#.............#.#.#.#.#.#...#...................................................................
..#######.#...#.#.#.#.#.#####.#####.###########.#.############.#####################.##.##.#.#.#.##.##.######.##################
#.......#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.......#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#.#..#..#........................
..#######.#...#.#.#.#.#.######.####...........#.#.#.###.....####.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#############################################
#.......#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.......#.#.###########.#.#...###.###..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#...................
..#######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.######.##.............#.#.#.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.##.######.#############
#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.......####.##########.................................................................................
........#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#####.###.#..#.#.#....#######.#####.#############################.#.#.#############.#############.######
#.##.####.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.###.##.#.#.###.#.###.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.
..#.....#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.......#.#..#...#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#...............................
#.#######.##.##.#.#.#.#.######.##.##.##.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.##################################
................................................................................................................................
########.#############.##################.#.##.##.#######.#.#.###########.######################################################
.....#......#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#..#.#...#######.#...#..#...#.#...#.#...#.#..#.#.#..#.....#.#.#.#................
###.####.##.#.#.###.##.#.###.#.#.#.##.#############.#.###.#.#.#.#.###.##.#.#.#.###.###.#.##.#.#.#.######.........###############
.....#...#..#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#...#.........#.#...#...#.#.#...#..#####.#...#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#...#.#.#.#.#................
###.####.####.#.###.##.#.###.#.#.#.##.#########.###.#.####.##.#.#.###.##...#.#.###...#.#.##.#.#.#.####.#.#######################
.....#......#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#...#.#.#...#..#.###.#...#.###.#.#..#.#.#..#.#..........................
##.#.###.####.#.###.##.#.###.#.#.#.##.###.........#.#.####.##.#.#.#.#.##...#.##.##.#...#.##.#.#.#.##...#.#################.#####
.#.###...#..#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#...#####.#####.#...#...#.#.#.###..#.###.#...#.###.#.#..#.#.#..#####...#....................
.....###...##.#.###.##.#.###.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.....#.#.####.##.#.#...#.##.#.#.##.##.#...#.##.#.#.#.##.....###.#.##############.##
##.###...#..#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.....#.###.#...#...#.#.#.###..#...#.#...#.###.#.#..#.#.#..#####.#.#.#.#................
.#.#.###.####.#.###.####.#.#.#.#.#.##...#####.#...#.##.###.##.#.#...#.###.##.##.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#####################
.....#...#..#.#..#..#..#...#.#.#.#..#.###..#..#####.#...#...#.#.#.###...........................................................
###.####.#.##.#.###.#.###.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.##.#.#.#.##.###.##.#.#.#.##########################################################.#
................................................................................................................................
#.###.###.################################.####################.################.###########.#######.###################.##.####
....#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.###.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#......
#.#########.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#########
....#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.#####...................................................................................
#.####.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#...#.#.#.#...##########.######.##################################.########.#.##############.#####
....#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.#.###.#.#..#.###.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.###.#.#.#..###.#.#...............
#.#.##.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#########.######
..###..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.#...#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#..#......................................
#.#.##.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#######################################
................................................................................................................................
###.#################################.##########.######.#.#.####################.###############################################
.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#...#.#.#######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#######...........................................
.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#####.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.####.#######################################
.##.............................................................................................................................
.#..########################################.###################################################################################
.##...#.......#.#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#.#.#...........................................................................
.#..#.#####.###.#.######.##.#.#.#.#.#.###.#####.#...###############.############.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.##.#####.#####
.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...###.#.#.#...#.#.....#...#..#.###..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.........
.#....#.......#.#.###.#.###.#.#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#...#.#.#.#.###.###.###.###.##.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.##.######.####.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.##.##.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.........############################################
.#....#.......#.#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#...#.....#.#.#.#...#.###.###...#######.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.......................
.##.#######.###.#.######.##.#.#.#.#.##.##.##.##.#####.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.################.#######
................................................................................................................................
##.########.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.############################################.#############################.######.#.#.#.######.###.##
....#.#..#..#######..#.#.#.#.......#.#.#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.###..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.
.#.##.##.####.....###############.##...#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.####.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.........
.#..#.#..#..####.##..#.....#.......#.###..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#....####.#####
##.##.##.#.##.....#.#####.#######.##.#.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.........
....#.#..#..###.###..#.....#.......#...#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.
##.##.##.#.##.#.#.#.###.######.#.####.##.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.##.#.#####################
.....................#.....#.###.#.#............................................................................................
##.######################.##.......#####.############.######.########.#.#################################################.######
.....................#.....######.##.#......#...#.#.###.........#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.............................................
##.######################.##.......#.###.####.###.#.#.#.##.##.###.#.#...#.#.#.#...##############################################
.....................#.....######.##.#......#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.##.##.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....
##.###################.#.###.......#.#.#.####...#.#.#.#######...#.#.#...#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#...###.##
.....................###.#.######.##.###....##.##.#.#.#...#.#.###.#.##.##.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.###.#.#.
##.########.#.#.##.#.#.....#.......#.#...##.#...#.#.#.#.###.....#...............................................................
....#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.####.#######.##.###.#..##.##.#.#.#.#.###.######.#######.###################.###.#.##.######################
##.##.#.#.############.....#.......#.#...####...#.#.#.#.........#.#..#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.###.#..#.#..#.#..............
.....................####.#######.##.###....##.##.#.#.###.#######.####.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.######.##.#...#.#.#.###.###
##.###################.....#.......#.#...####...#.#.#.#.........#.#..#.#.###..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#...#..
.....................####.#######.##.###....##.##.#.#.###########.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.###...#
.#.####.##############.....#.......#.#...#.##...#.#.#.#.........#.#..#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#...#..
##.#.................####.###.######.###.#..##.##.#.#.########.##.#.##.#.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.###############
...###################.....#.......#.#.#.####...................................................................................
##...................####.######.#.#.#......##.##########################.######################################.#####.#########
...###################.....#.#.#.###.###.####...#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.###.#...#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.###........
##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.##.......#.#......##.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#####
.....................#.....######.##.###.####...................................................................................
##.###########.#.#.#.###.###.......#.#......####.####.###############################.###.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.......#.#.#...#######.....###.#.###.###.##.#.#...#.....#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.###.################
##.#####...#####.....####.##.###.#.#.#....###.#######.###.###...#.#.......#.#.#.#...#...#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.......##.##.#.##.####.....#.#.#.#.#.###.##.#.#...#.....#.#.##.##.##.###.##.#.#.##.##.###.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.###.................
##.#.#.#.............###.###.......#.#....#.#.#.#####.###...#...#.#..#....#.#.#.#...#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.################.##.#.#.######.##.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.###.##.##.######.#.#.##.#############################################
................................................................................................................................
.###.####.##########.####################################################.#######################.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#########
...#..#.#...#.....#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...........
.###.##...#####.###.##.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#...#.#...################################
...#..###...#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.###.##...###.....#.##...##.....................................................................................................
...#..###...####.##.#..#..##########.#################.################.######################################.######.#.#.#.#.#.
.###.##...###.....#########.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..###.#..############
...#..###.#.####.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.###.##.........................................................................................................................
...#..#.#.###.#####.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#################################.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.
.###.##.#.#.#.....#.#...#.#.###.#.#####.#.###..#.#.#.#....#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#..
.#.#..#.#...#.#####.##.##.#.#...#.#.....#.#...##.#.#.##.###....#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##################################################
...#.##.#.###.....#.#...#.#.###.#.#####.#.###..#.#.#.#..#.##.###.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..............
.###..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#...#.#.....#..#..##.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.############.##
...#.##.#...#.#####.#...#.#.###.#.##.##.#.###...................................................................................
.###..#.#.###.#.#.#.##.##.#.#...#.#..#..#..#..###.#.#.####.###.##.#.#.#.#.##.##.##############.#################################
...#.##.#...#.....#.#...#.#.###.#.#####.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.....#...#.#.#.#.#.#...#...#.............................................
.###..#.#.###.##.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.....#.#.#.###########.#.#.#.#.##.##.#######################.########################
...#.##.#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#...#.#.#####.#.#.#.###.#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#..#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.............................................
```

Comment: Back in 2014 you claimed an incredible [17 character score](https://gist.github.com/jonathanmorley/8058871#gistcomment-981796) on Glob of [Regex Golf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf). Nobody has come close; somebody got 21 eventually; I've only been able to get 22 (the [best published one is 23](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9221685)). Could you please share your amazing solution now? I think it's been long enough :) Or give a hint as to what schema was used. It would be sad for your solution to disappear into the mists of time. (You've ignored my emails, so I'm reduced to trying this now.)

Answer (score 5):

## Score: 8127 ([validation](https://tio.run/##tV3LbhvJFV27vqLHd0EKwzmwk00wiLKb2QYIJotAEAJGoqxWJJIgqbE1hr/daT677ququshwYJFqdldXnbr33Gdrlm@bx8X8z9/X7R@z649/@ktYrNpP7Xz6/O@XaXdkNBrRwBeqz2DHcfwtxF/CuB6wP4szkbg9jCOnYyE5BswpFawfxdiESpxNSMov7E/NTQBV@w3n3fg15GUHFxFN5yLwCSCesgVvQiT9SaXOkxNwpnkhBbUuCTWidoasgAnGfgKwhqja1OFa5GsBLnCfIk4KBcMheSugcEoQMnyagIG9c0sMFACglohq5AA5VrJpKXi3hLEMuCcVGgQDwsDnhsvIN8qxCnTBF4YIwuF4qFGdxLhl4EsZSNMtiobTZwHe0Mwa4gwSsY0FBslMkHMH0xuYblqF1XBPCRVrTnyLJJXCM8dIeC/5m@F4A@Q5U@@a9IoxHGqUbzlsa4giv86VvuKtgCUl4Twnt9Rqwz09ZAe3aACpI9j9hrJZIqBOwbB9DSQ9nwltAkUBC6NWa@FtAc5wiz2TLmgAAgEU02qZ2zXQZgYtMz62KIlAB25CEJ66HhxFUWCJ0UaJW44z0Bz@tZwAfP8C5yLuqiFUJqL8Rue5kKjxCYXAoJp/sh7RwIXlszjIJiic0KIc5SLGsqyhSjwMsOZ1248ya1hDvBjk1yQngHo@HuQ2BW8Zg4ORwd5tjRqiULkHcEYABpl2ZFaUSRWgKklVmCoZAry3BXAWC6TcQZwxHz2B/1NOEPYOoo8LYOgCktsLOv8FMzBBXgJy6gAkI53o6zCAxgebJaSZDJXW0PbWat3XrBoCVZseyRWSwUuotnbFE0Iy5g2FoXBKq0rdBRTYAlxQxZJawgOTi43GpKaIiXs1xGWXyGFPjB8KjDsKorZqsh7GA7jwecUOCS6umxdzSivdRT4BXEr3c5VCpGtGw1BHJjuE4VsAlPliQPlGw/MoUSUDuLzA9GoIwWX1dUwn82wlgrqDITn@oBpMJBu@V6LyEMGRrsEMZ1h@1AghUqbzLGWFPWQ4Q8QgA4MaIQ2XSAWUmF156PgvVN8FxS07Se9Zpmqr0jRFKTbkQzPEGgC6oKFO@Oyh@CpUUlFmYMmEJlC4QD7QmCHEBJCVf6TtLlChKKFWuwohQc5UhzOBxbnli5DW2wFe0BkZkkEihlqZc7gr5PBFicU5Y1ZhWK9YBqwKdQ1nKvPZ3FDMhNVBUcY6nGmO4VvfjOZmUzSZlQBDmGfoFhQ0tuheANQ5NEHST@EKir1PWJ6yiQAG@D2DQySksmRxXhYoLgfA4QgUyWBBcIqhGzF4/aglojqX2Sxv4eSQnN84m9QKf/SQZHzkvEMMpQ/CQFuAy4bkyQkkm5Lqn2vIxClVPiHcoBgodKTOMMc4T22sqhnORxjVkwuekCBreC/gq0C09QKZbh7Ep@Ei@cXsExZ1XAyHxaxEJXIYw4jo0u5qnllglGxwHsHUnhX8JWO4u1ehCqHgcrisin0nGqz8CMqGDBfimoFBIjxbcKHcw4CTw3lhyACrcb4twLlxAPITQE92phlBJe64eHCKyq3X14WC2QKXVv5CBHDREgmUdwXTHA/Kdw3I4Xpeakl4DqpIZJdCEoqTLCInebarqp@yKUhCyhyBrAdVuWQQ3sCla3MYqgXwaRXl4QKKQIS3BSjYiJr2GvcBh3xuH/bjF@pJhsFFhlDnT58cxJp2TwzziOJCZn2oirIkVbESJvJGqJtAJjAYKKBJBuenjEYjrJfP7WZ89f1@9tDcPc7u/rv74wTjl6ufQ9O9Hharpm3aebOazj/Nxts/ZfDTx8N3x@@fEt9vX1@uu/s8Ldr5@Oblpr29ebqddO8/fjx@6t67X07Huh@3V2yA9qH50t3jZrQV9NFktJWG0S2/yfa1mm1eV/NmdN9OPy3m0@fnt2Z6/zS9m803zexluXlr7mbPz@vR7sLf23W7md1f39z8On1ez6yVXN0ay7@63V2@xev@YT1uJ0@TZTtZPkWL7uY7nb@Nb9q/fpg8df/av11vr5w87d9vBT6Haf@2ep3FQxywur4e0ajogsOK9peZV@xWevqCnX/NRtuu@8vkbbvyP9rl@ObD5OPkw@Snbpdu9h8mH@QqugmM90D8cD1uf/wyefrx7arD4b6ZLzZ7qPYHJx1kV@7m8SnKlVr7kRRGPckeVoxO02NQ8El3@9stVwl1LG8vr8@bdvk8a5bTzeNBvOKZh5frm9tgz/3dZvXW/Xz3gulyOZvfj9v58rVTyKvwbvblbrbcNL/8/ddfVqvFanvWcrpeh3fdKp5n805Hr6/b7dHVtO0E@Jfd6e1iPn4Y/fY4az6t2vvmcbpuvrbfmtXi87q793ozm943i4fm6/b230ZX/WDd2rud2x62h/zH4vNupO2I3QWfNo/N19OF39yxt4rwZYdmO@8Ud7QXrS0Muwvte/1zPvuynN11O9Jx0nQ17T6tdsjt57Ad2t7rd90tx2P2d1Z6xtm@d5CNRzsOGV3tznfA2xJFszjdcdLcLZ5fX@bN16dvzcvretP8Z7anlG4u@x087FvI7cbLYjVrNo/T@QGn3dZ0o@jd3m32ara@ZrwcOlC7gz/sFPbn5O3a9Q74abO9dAf85nH7/vy8@NzOP3XDTNeL@c/N@6/dgN/ed5NYrtr5ZrwbYXdNN8Lv0@f2vvtqfddN/MTkL1e4W7xuz6XTZQ@jfy1eV83uxO2VX3efvjXjt8Vrs9kevF987pb9/v1@DLZNx/He0/ur5qfmcOnnjsTXV6Or79/3D1b2P/cfoxedjlD0WZxJ1kH3UHwk7HMw/c8@MXOoRMnP0a9REsc6KA@ZVwZxuvEr/yzO5HckYwKJD9YEFAJEKQT4YAC/6OTGSgTImMDJMYaCllwEjqP2Q9JJnk5ypRGAgcDhGV/w6CQarS9OMkDAzgGKZAAmAgcRp0hGo/nIO9FBQUhsliEDxuQsBA4VTUsICZ58R7sp8LbOi6Xj9JEhYOJ35AJzbTDxFtrQT@4Ecf8xRgCuDjkI6MPxRvFp5GXAZRGVOjb2yOQmvutsvywtIGgVBpdIGwEQuTpAYi8TCEQbrpRP8q2iSo@INQkI0eUTgN4yeNBHjNbfWWikQYNadAOkcvRaeQTFYeYIJXGXyLJaCChbwJRDIgBfsKJzOMXHvEkKAS4gwVapCIHEBnAEjnF7z9BMthUCKJMBGAx1TBNECFC8YRECjMkJSnE9BGKxgL8RYj4CPiYq3OQoIYxIhSLjKIqpNg8K9YZCAJSg1NAb/d4OCqr3acg2fAKBeB36mmA5CZQVQMXU4JsutRLCX@qvCWIof3kWwUrMOP9xC3kSR87tIVIdS8ktM8TQ5Uu3IIzNpLaIIXJ9JPW7whehq6y2ASHjZPkt84hguiJkWkBTXMQmReLluojcJyTtigAGFWmRkX4vyZsmERAZewgiNyhc@2O@DJCBQH@nEPlswoXp1VqNZhoPUo6YaQGE0gdKOnvH5WoEDOMRezTSIXfFJVhbzGeqjRiRj4AnnOQoTIjdLyLnWpiOCFhM5uhLCQLaqDDmthRPugRuWJJHgDkWpr9lREYsdHW9rdhnMhDAiQn5aSLSpT4zYigd1@tBCByOBRlsK28DxNyzKFIlyD2tQkAF29a1POyK@dbSAhUDRZxgyIARYskcjCK2yBKRsppsuzipWVogIFHZDjLdbuUFKVuupp5HwM92uJkGN63EYjvtnpgIePkuHf3y4M8PXohgCEXsphsIKBcRkAkR@JM1Mlwyru2dYEohYDhPgJnK5CJHdsaCyPAzIiYk@MkfUgTt@89ezgYkIrT@u2AnAgzeizbPDw9U2ow5UTKvmZABZWpP/jSlZMBQp5SkWDIgGUslCYwdAnyDZKdHo6ECRNMtzHWxcLWPHJPOXyI9Gi0sxAl8V7Z5FqNPTpEvA/or6bTvjUpwU5Qg26SmklPRnGTIB@W67AELXoqSYJtUK3efCFnMjFt8eUgEwSTMHQoQ0Pl7bhG473FEIJ2FgxfykoWVtGjQ5pxiNyOAdH5UGQHb0bWlJRNkiC7howzI/CgZJlwH/UBWBsxwKNb4YMXdWuXsoN9DgBLiRLFbF8kAS/ClbmYmxr2UtGiukd4Oei2IshTk5dgLETCTQ45PKLUA2v2HacKEo@FpbmLmEgHbuU/weUIG7JRbKQJGzA2XHW0eSBd3pG9XjgB7ICGnBWa8H6dhkUOAWBUzLgLAKNkJjvPSukbAEiHAzF0UbscFTNO8mUyIRJhKsW8RIFM/rkcJldGkUiYUQVpMdEHHtXFzY5ylUl55AgFtXMxS@m4CStDjEIBUUchI0Kq4gEQRJVo3Lw3sOyi0s6DT77ETZdog5tGLyoPMmsoMCRd9slIhROYeJwqWqowh87dxjigWffi1YGnv43bYRLQm6n8w84RILNlLUxu1PscDZzkh8cdgYgSsPgW/p8VuWbB4UnRbCFkJcZGaKFe20QP4aQnd/GJ9FWCX04isQNhClwXNVsHVNt3HS4KRSIsrQapFxCzeQOBMifoGw0ogIP1/VhtSVVhxWQIBSRRRR0mEwIk4SKchwS0aJ1hD0ihd4UHkfQVwW6nS5Pw6kmGHnJqHgIile4k8qaGMr80wA379TBbUjYBe18ciIrKaPuyAyasgQhTUdXRBKQTUIq2AKV1DJSsMZHIUlyAiBJCsGXmdUUa6GDoQNrM08f9v4VS288I5cjqosqbHz9JEKtCX7bItUrkaegkCRq7llCXLtgak/jNSdnkEjloeMCT7S8luOe5DeQgw0@sgYFp4LmleYpVyMsAUjGwEHMGTGdFU2sBJNRuNPEH3mxJs8lH5QCSCZs0@VhVYywDrX9blJxL9l4k4VhZZWRVYVM@Z8FKi/CRq@7pf0Apete1gwwblYEbhp6o4yhK@6Bfkga@X30nVjCyjrRCQgYvy3bykiWqoOWTL3R4joW5k6SiJ/l@/yAjRUHN4C9Dxk12fgd1xZpgON8MHwy8JLoWTV6PyU/pxGc8rxkm/JKhEu6n75LTOktMKiAKTphBwW1blzEVVU6bGmUuWNGEcAaQQiNxS2acCaE/abbzWAh6ckMObFpIuEukQ2kdg/zNwkixo2iLfRYLTPpAqSISYBSjDA5GlSjQcm/kzsytPumRW96gZLqK3yDmvNVnxBUWdVHYzkd24IiwySUSUgyLJMtqhAE7Umf5Rqz0LcB1bo5okKSNAlhKU8@W3S5o5ZrMfC@ZTKjIwMZ8LAPy2BYuMdJTA1NxCwOFtTcd2CiP7@AFXc2nCQraL3LFUzqMEbmdu3G@uyvfpSKCgz13Lv8ygqYx73MDgC7Hdve@HC2IiugVaJysD3xzn6RAvWsnaG5GX8hFQfb1wkpM5toLZ9SeexfAR8AqFbrdVedh80ukMArruCZS4N7mw2UAg7iu2ar5CvfMJI7cBwHgahTc2J7LeYJXfQfCLhjADAS0D2t1Tld8oaBqGgTIIhgxod4/cSilQNAXVH8oycHHFxGJqP2fl@C8pDDQdspqRxdQW5TEbVySQsovE4AHrQQxKc@tpC1CiF@IRjwwCtnOiGal/nifhzQn6h9H9E@LHoyALnQxA3cNDuhJgWQqjr9BFALrCzgMvijijkBN0B09CBsweNsPap1rkknX7DAJ2D1vyCSRKlxRIP2PDySkgUYm2@EnXinMektHnE93pfw))

-11 thanks to Anders Kaseorg

```
.....#.....#....#................##........#.##...........#...........#........#..................#.................#...........
.#.#...#.#...#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.##..#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#..#.##..#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.##..#.##.#.#.#.##.#...#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#####.#.#####.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#####.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.###.#.#..#.##..#.#.#.#..#.##.##.#.#####.#.#.##.#.....#.#.....#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.....###.##.#.#########.#.....#.#.##.#.##.##.#.#.#.##..#..#.#.....#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.##.##....#.#.........#.##.#.####..#.#.....#.#.#.#....##.##.#.#.#.#####.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#..#..##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.###..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.######.#.#.#.....#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.######.##.#####.#.##.#####.#.
.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.....##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#......#..#.....#.#..#.....#.#.
.#.#.#..#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.....#.#####.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#########.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.###.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#..######.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#...#..#.#####.#.#####.#..#.........#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.##......#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#.#.##.....#.#.....#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##..#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.######.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#..###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#..#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#####.####.##.#.#.#.##.#.#..#......#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#####.#.##.###.#.#..#..#.#.##...#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#....#.#.##..#.#.#.##.#.#.....#....#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.....#.#..#...#.#.#.##.##.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#..#.##.#.####.#.#.##.##.#.##.####.#.#.##.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.###.#.
.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###..#.#.##..#.#....#####..#..#.#..#...#..#.####.#.#.##.##.#.#.#...#.#.
.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#..#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####...#.##.#..#.####.#.##...#.##.##.#.##.#.#.####..#.#.#..#..#.###.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#####.#.##.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#..#.#.#####...#..#.#.#..#..#.#..#.#.#....#.##.#.#.##.##...#.#.#.#.#.
.#.###.#.#..#.#####.#.....######.#.#####...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.....#.#.#.##.#...##.##.#.##.#.#.#.##..#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#...#.####.#.......#.#.#......#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#..#..#.#..#.#.#.#####.#.####.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#######.#.#.##.#.#.###.#.#.##.#.#.......#....#.#.##########.#.#.
.#.#.#.##.#####.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#..#.......#.#.#..#.#.#...#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#.##.#.####..........#.#.#.
.#####..#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.###.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.#..#.#...##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.
.....#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#.#..#####...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#...#.#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.####.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.
.#.#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#.#.##.....##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.###.#.##.#.#....#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.
.#.#.#.##.##.##.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.....#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#..##.#####.#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.#.
.#.######.#####.#.#.#.#.##.####.#.##..#..#.#.#.#.###.##......#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.##.#.####.#.#.#.
.#......#.....#.#.#.#.#..#....#.#..##.#.##.#.#.#..#...#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#####.#.#.#.####.#.#.##.##.#.#.#..#.#....#.#.#.#.
###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.####.##..#..#.#.#.#.###.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.....#.#.#.#....#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.
..#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#....#..#.##.##.#.#.#...####.#.#.##.#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##.##.#.#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#.#.
#.....#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##.##..####.#.#.#.#....#.#.#..#####.#.#.####.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.
..##.##.#.....#.#.#.#.#.####.#..#..#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.###..#.#.#....#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.##.##.#.#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#.#.
.###..#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#....#.#.##.##..#.##.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#...#.##.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#..#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##...#.#.
...#.##.#..#..#.#####.#.#.##.#..#..#.##....#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.##..#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.##.##.#.#.#..#.#.#..##.##.#.
.#.#.#..#.##.##.....#.#.#..#.#.##.##..#.#.##.#.#####..#.#..#..#.##.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#..#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##...#.#.
.#.#.#.##..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#..#..#.##.#..#.#.....##.#.#.###.#..#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#####.#.#.#..#.#.##.####.#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#..#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.###.#..#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#...#.#.####.#.#####.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.##.#..#....#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.##...#.#.#####.#.#.##.#...#.#.##.#.####.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#..#.#.##.#.##.#.#..#.#.#..#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.....#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#....#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.....#.#.##.#..#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.#...#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.###..#.#.#####.#.#.#..#####..#.#.#.#.
.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.######.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.##.#.#...#.#.#.#.##...#.######.#.
.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#......#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#...###.#.#.#..#.#.#......#.#.
.###.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.######.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.####..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##..#.####.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.
...#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#......#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#####..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#####..#.#.#.#..##....#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.
.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#..#.###.......##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.....#.##.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.
.#.#.#.##.#.#.#####.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.##...#.#.#.#..#.######.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##
.#####.######.....#.#.#.####.#.#.#..#.#.#####.#.##......#####.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##...
.....#......#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.##.#.....#.#..#.#.#.##..####.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.###.#.#..#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.###.#.#..##.#
.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.##.##.#.##.#.#..#.##..#.#.#.##.#.#.#..####.#.#...#.#.#.##.#####....#.#.#....#..#.##..#..
..#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#..#..#.#..#.#.#.##..#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.....#.#.##.#.#.#.##.##..#.##.#
.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.####.#.###.#.#.##.#.#..#.##..#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.##.#.#####.#.#.###.#.##.#..#.#.#.#..#.##.##..#..
..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#....#.#...#.#.#..#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##..#.#.....#.#.#...#.#..#.#.##.#.#.#.##..#..#.##.#
.##.#####.#.#####.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#...#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.####.#.#..#.##.#####..
..#.....#.#.....#.#.#####.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#...#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#....#.#.#.#####.....#.#
#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.....#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.######.....##.#.##..
..#.#.#####..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##......#.#.#.#######.########......#.#.#..#.#..#.#
.##.#.....#.##.####.#.#.#.#..######.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.......#........#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.##..
..#.#.#.#.#..#....#.#.#.#.#.##......#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#..#.#..#.#
.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.###....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.##..
..#.#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##..###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.######.#..#.#
.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#####.######.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.##.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..######.#......#.#.##..
..#.#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.#####.##.#.####.#.....#......#.#.######.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##..#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##....#.#.#.#.##.#..#.#
.##.#.#.###.##.#.##.#.....#..#.#....#.##.#.##.#.##.#####....#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.##.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.##.########.#.##..
..#.#.#..#...#.#..#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.##..#.#.####..#.....#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#..#........#.#..#.#
.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.####.#####..#.#.#..##.#.#....#.##.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.##.#.#####.#.#####.#.#.######.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.#
..#.#..#.#.#.#.#...#......#.####.#.##..#.#.#.##..#.###.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#####.####..#.#....####.#........####.#.#..#.###...
.##.#.##.#.#.#.##.###.#.#.#....#.#..#.##.#.#..##.#...#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#........#.#####.#....#.#.##.#.#....#.#.#.##...#.#.
..#.#..#.#.######...#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#####.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.....#.#.#.##.#..#.###.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.
.##.#.##.#......#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.....#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#.####.#.###.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#..#.#.##...#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.#.
..#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#####.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#....#.#..#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#..##.##.#.##.#.#.########.
.##.#.##.#####..#.#.....#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.##.#####.##.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##..#..#.#..#.#.#........#.
###.#..#....###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#........#..#.#.#.#####.....#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.##.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.
..#.#.##.##...#.#.#.#.#######..#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.####..#.##.##.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..##.#.#...#.#..#.#.#.#####..#.
.##.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.......#.##.#.#.#.#####.##..#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#....#.##..#..#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.######.....#.##.
..#.#.##.##.#.#.###.#.#.##.##..#.#.#.###...#..#.####.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.##..#.##.##.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#.#.....###.##.####.
.##.#..#.####.#...#.#.#..#..#.##.#.#...#.#.#.##....#####.#.#.#####.#.#..#.##..#..#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#..#....#.
..#.#.##....#.##.##.#.#.##.##..#.#.#.#.#.#...###.#.....#.#.#.....#.#.#.##....##.##.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.######.#.#.#.##.##.##.#.##.
.##.#.###.#.#..#..#.#.#..#..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#..#.#.###..#.#.##.#.#####.#.##......#.#.#.#..#..#..#.#..#.
..#.#...#.#.#.###.#.#.#.##.#####.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#.#.#.##.#...#.##.#..#.#.....#.#..#.#.#.####.#.#.##.##.##.#.##.
.##.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#..#.....#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#..#.#.#.#..#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#...####.#..#..#..#.#..#.
....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#...#.#.####.#.#.#.#.##.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#....#.#.##.##.####.##.
.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#..#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#..#..#....#..#.
.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.##.##.#.##.##.
.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.####.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#..#..#.#.##..#.
.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.######.#.#....#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.##.##.#####..##.
.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#......#.#.#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##..#..#.....#.###.
.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#....####.#.#.#..#..###.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.##.##.#.#.#...#.
.#.#.##.#.#.#.#####..#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.##.##...#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.##.#.#....#.#.#.####.#.#.#####.##..#..#.#.#.#.#.#.
.#.#..#.#.#.#.....#.##.....#.#####.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#..#..##.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#....#.#.#.....#..#.##.######.#.#.#.
.#.#.####.#.##.#######.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.##.###..#.#.#.#.#..#####.######.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.##......#.#.#.#.
.#.#....#.#..#.......#.#.###.##.##.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#..#...#.####.#.#.#.##...#......#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#..#.#.##.#.#.#.
.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#.#.#...#..#..#.#.#.#.##..#.#.####.#.#.#....#.#####..#.#.#.#.#.##.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#####.##.#.##.#.####.#.##
.#.#.####.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.###.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.##.....#.##.#.###.#..#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.....#..#.#..#.#....#.#...
.#.#....#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.####..#.#.#.#...#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#..#.#...#.#.##.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.##.##.#
.#.#.#.##.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.##.#.#...#..#.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#..#..#..
.#.#.#..####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#####.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.##.#..#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#
.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##.#.....#.#.#.#..#####.#.#.#.#########.#.#.###.#..#.##.#.######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#..#..
.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#...##.....#.#.#.#.........#.#.#..#..#.##..#.#......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#
.#####.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.###.#..#.##.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#..
.....#..#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#...#.#.#####.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.
.#.####.#..###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#######..#.###.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.
.#....#.#.##...#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.......#.##...#..#..#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#..#.#.#.####..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.
###.#.#....#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.##.#.#.##.##...#.#####.###.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.##.#.#....#.##.#.###.#.#.#.#.#..#.
..#.#####.##.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.....#.#.#..#..#.#.#....#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##..#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.##.
.####......#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.##.#.##.##.#.#.#.#..#.
....#.#.#.##.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#....####.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#########.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#..#.#####.##..#.#..#..#.#.#.#.#.##.
.#.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.......#.#.......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.....#..#.##.#.##.####.#.#.#..#.
.#..#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##.#..#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##..#.#..#....#.#.#.##.#.
.#.##.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##..#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#####.##.#.#.#.#..#.##.#.##.#.##.#.#..#.#.
.#..#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.##.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#..#.#.#.#.#.##.####..#.#..#.#.#.##.#.
.#.##.#.##.###.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.##..#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.######....#.##.#.##.#.#..#.#.
.#..#.#..#..#..#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#..#.##.#.#.##.#.#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#......#.#.##..#.#..#.#.#.##.#.
.#.##.#.##.##.######.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.##.#.#..#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#....##.#.##.#.#..#.#.
.#..#.#..#..#......#.#.#.#######.....#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#..#.#.##..#.#..#.#.##.#.#.
.#.##.#.##.###.#.#.#.#.#.......#.#.#.#.######.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.##.#..#.##.#.##.#..#.#.#.
.#..#.#..#...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.########...#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#..#.#.##..#.#..#.#.####.#.
.#.##.#.##.#.#####.#.#.#.#####.#........#.#.#.#.#.#.###.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.##.#..#.##.#.##.###..#.#.
.#..#.#..#.#.....#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#..#....###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#.#..#.#.##..#.#..#.....##.#.
.##.#.#.##.#.##.####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.#...#.#.#.##.#.##...#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.####.#.##.#..#.##.#.##.#.#..#.#.
..#.#.#..#.#..#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####.##.#.#..#.####.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#....#.#..#.#.##.##.#..#.#.#.##.#.
.##.#.#.##.#.##.#.######.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#..#.#.#.##....###...#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.##.#.####..#.##.#.#..#.#.
..#.#.#..#.#..#.#......#.#.#.#####.#.##.#.##.##.#.#..#.##...##.##.....#.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#.#.#####..#.#..#.#....#.##..#.#.#.##.#.
.##...#.##.#.####.#.#.######.....#.#..#.#..#..#.#.#.##.###.###.##.#.#.#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.....#.##.#.##.#.#.##..#.##.#.#..#.#.
..#.#.#..#.#...####.#......#.#.######.#.#.###.###.#..#...#......#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#..#.####.#.#..#.##..#.#.#.##.#.
.##.#.#.##.#.#....#.#.#.#.##.#......#.#.#.#.....#.#.##.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.##....#.#.#.##..#.##.#.#..#.#.
..#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.##.#.#####.#.#.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.#.####.#.#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#.#.#.#.######.##.#.#.#..#.#####.#.#.##.#.
.##.#.#.##.#.#.#..#.#.#.#.##.#..#.#.....#.#.#.#.#.#.##.#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#......#..#.#.#.#.##.....#.#.#..#.#.
```

Comment: Feed this back into your script again—you can knock down another 11 walls.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Nice, never thought to try that.